# Change attribution model in custom reports GA

Tags: google-analytics

I am working on a Google analytics project, Google Analytics uses last interaction attribution model by default for reporting. Is there a way to generate a `Custom report` (from customization => custom reports) but use `first interaction` attribution model instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change default attribution model for all other reports then MFC in Google Analytics Standard. There are basically two ways to workaround though:

- You can play with MFC/Attribution reports and change attribution models there and try to set up custom report with First Interaction model that satisfies your needs (not all the dimensions/metrics will be available).
- You can export data to some other storage (i.e. Google BigQuery), and build your attribution by your own from the raw data.

Comment: How can i achieve the first point (`You can play with MFC/Attribution reports and ...`) ?